# Disable metadata in Claws Mail

Tags: email, privacy

How to disable the following metadata in the E-Mail Header in Claws Mail? In the **accountrc** file i didn't find the right line.

```
AF:
NF:0
PS:10
SRH:1
SFN:
DSR:
MID:
CFG:
PT:0
S:myaddress@example.com
RQ:
SSV:sendingserver.com
NSV:
SSH:
R:<receiver@example.com>
MAID:6
X-Claws-Privacy-System:
X-Claws-Sign:0
SCF:#imap/LOCAL_CHOOSEN_MAILBOX_NAME/Sent
X-Claws-Auto-Wrapping:1
X-Claws-Auto-Indent:1
X-Claws-End-Special-Headers: 1
```

(the common "Date, From, To,.." following after)

Answer (score 1):

These headers are used internally by Claws while composing an email for sending.  They track things like which sender address you've chosen, which outgoing mail server to use when sending, if the email should be signed or encrypted, and similar things.

The headers are stripped out during the sending process, which you can verify by sending yourself an email.  You can't disable them because doing so would keep Claws from working.

Comment: You are right! I found it in the sent / draft / queued for sending folders only on my own email provider. To remove also the given **localhost name** of the machine in the **Message-ID**, set "msgid_with_addr=" to "0" in the ~/.claws-mail/accountrc while Claws-mail is not running (in the Claws-mail settings menu, i didn't find this value).